# Identify current step in page life cycle

Tags: asp.net, lifecycle

Is there a way to see where exactly a given piece of code is executing with regards to the current Page life cycle?  Closest thing I can think of is to look at the call stack in the debugger and attempt to determine from there.  But I thought there might be some standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx). If you want to know from code, use [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx).